# What kind of tools does projects like hadoop,hive used to generate shell utilies?

Tags: shell, maven

I always wrote startup shell by myself. As you know it's boring and easily be broken.

I was wondering is there any tools can generate such thing automatically. especially in maven.

please introduce some for me. thank you!

Comment: The Application Assembler plugin might be helpful [see here](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/index.html)

Comment: Thanks,I'll give it a try.